# html concatenation in loop syntax error: unexpected identifier (jquery+html+php)

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to concatenate html inside a variable in loop and return with populated. but i'm getting

error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +=

my code.

```
<a style="cursor: pointer" id="addmore">More Entree ?</a>

<?php $json = JSON_encode($entree); ?>

<script>

function populate() {
 var json = <?php echo $json; ?>;
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
   var obj = json[i];
   var option += '<option value="' + obj.id + '">' + $.trim(obj.title) + '</option>';
  }
return option;
}

$(function (c) {
   $("a#addmore").click(function () {
    console.log(populate());
     //$("p").append('<select>' + populate() + '<select>');
    });

</script>
```

[image: json]

Comment: do you have an example of the json outputted?

Comment: okay, put json example in next edit.

Comment: You should not edit your original code based on the answers you get as then the answers will stop making sense. If you try additional things, put them below the original code / question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't re-declare your variable in the same scope over-and-over and expect it to add to its previous value.

You need something like:

```
function populate() {
  // only declare the variables once
  var json = <?php echo $json; ?>,
      option = '',
      obj;

  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    obj = json[i];
    option += '<option value="' + obj.id + '">' + $.trim(obj.title) + '</option>';
  }

  return option;
}
```

**Edit:** See [an example here](http://jsbin.com/wimayi/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: @fab_s3 See the example I added, it works fine. Are you sure the error is generated in that part of the script?

Answer (score 0):

The the syntax error isn't really due to where the variable is declared. The code would still run without an exception (albeit with invalid results) if we changed "+=" to "=".

```
var option = '<option value="' + obj.id + '">' + $.trim(obj.title) + '</option>';
```

Simply put, declaring a variable and applying a += operator at the same time is not valid JavaScript.

But why?

According to [the MDN doc for 'var'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> var varname1 [= value1 [, varname2 [, varname3 ... [, varnameN]]]];

Here, the "=" is explicitly listed as the only valid symbol between 'var' and the first value.

That's because in this case, "=" represents **initialization**, not **assignment**.

Again, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed.

It's a subtle but important difference:

Initialization occurs during the pre-execution stage, whereas "+=" (performing addition, then assigning the result) counts as "executing code". And because all variables must be parsed before any code executes, += can't occur until *after* all the variables have been initialized! You've got a Catch-22!

So, after a var declaration, only "= x", commas, and more variable declarations are valid until the end-of-statement ; is reached.